# Chrome keeps cookies despite of setting them expired on the server

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I bumped into this issue when trying to clean-up redundant OpenIdConnect.nonce cookies. These cookies are added automatically by the OpenIdConnect middleware when a client tries to access a protected resource (a web service). After setting the cookie the middleware redirects the client to an authentication service which uses the cookie for it's own security purposes.

My actual problem was the "Bad Request - Request Too Long" error my acceptance tests were getting because the requests got filled with dozens of those nonce cookies. That happened, in turn, becase my tests tried to visit some protected resources multiple times without proper authentication.

The logical decision (before fixing the tests) was to remove redundant cookies by setting the expiration timestamp to past:

```
private void ClearNonceCookies(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // Clear nonce cookies to prevent the request from growing too big over time
    foreach (var key in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Where(c => c.StartsWith("OpenIdConnect.nonce.")))
    {
        var cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies[key];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie.Expires = SystemTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-5);

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

That didn't work because of not such an obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

My test environment used an http endpoint while it also had this setting in the Web.config:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
```

That line configures the web server to make all cookies "secure" although I was not using an https binding.

As mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the "secure" directive anymore (new in Chrome 52+ and Firefox 52+) and hence my expiration requests were ignored by the browser.

The resolution would be either to change the requireSSL setting to false or use an https binding.